# Testing with Recharts, trying to insert data into BarChart component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, recharts

I'm trying to insert data into the `data` attribute of `<BarChart/>`, but I'm having trouble.

Below is my test. I had to mock the `ResponsiveContainer` with px sizes so the inner chart would render, but you can see I'm trying to squish `OriginalModule.BarChart` in there, but that's not working.

`BarChart` is not its own component, it's just sitting in my App. Please let me know how I can get the data in there so the chart renders correctly. Thanks very much in advance.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from '../components/app/App';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';

const mocks = [
  {
    name: 'Kiwi',
    quantity: 65,
    unitPrice: 2,
  },
  {
    name: 'Pineapple',
    quantity: 65,
    unitPrice: 2,
  },
];

jest.mock('recharts', () => {
  const OriginalModule = jest.requireActual('recharts');
  return {
    ...OriginalModule,
    ResponsiveContainer: ({ children }: any) => (
      <OriginalModule.ResponsiveContainer width={800} height={800}>
        <>
          <OriginalModule.BarChart data={mocks} />
          {/* {children} */}
        </>
      </OriginalModule.ResponsiveContainer>
    ),
  };
});

test('renders App', () => {
  const { container } = render(<App />);
  const headerText = screen.getByText(/Market Fresh/i);
  expect(headerText).toBeInTheDocument();
  const kiwi = screen.getByText(/kiwi/i);
  expect(kiwi).toBeInTheDocument();
});

test('gets veggie data', async () => {
  const { container, debug } = render(<App />);
  userEvent.click(screen.getByText(/fruit/i));
  userEvent.click(screen.getByText(/veggies/i));
  userEvent.click(screen.getByText(/submit/i));
  const veggieSelector = screen.getByText(/veggies/i);
  expect(veggieSelector).toBeInTheDocument();
  debug(undefined, Infinity);
});
```